# Indiscernability of identicals (HoTT)

Tags: homotopy-type-theory

In 1.12 of the HoTT book it is mentioned that it is a simple exercise to show that indiscernability of identicals follows from path induction. I am getting the sense that it is a special case but I am struggling to explicitly write down what is necessary to see this. I’m open to someone just giving me the answer, but in fact — if someone had the patience — I would prefer a hint.

Comment: Is “HoTT” a textbook?

Comment: @TymaGaidash Yes, that's [the standard abbreviation for it](https://homotopytypetheory.org/book/) (and it's clear from the tag).

Comment: It’s the standard text for the topic that is tagged: Homotopy Type Theory.

Comment: "HoTT" (i.e. "homotopy type theory") is usually used to refer to the whole subject.  The book in question is generally referred to as "the homotopy type theory book" or "the HoTT Book".

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a proposed solution to the excercise.

Let $D: A \to \mathcal{U}$ and define $C(x,y,p) :\equiv D(x) \to D(y)$. Clearly we can define a $c: \Pi_{x:A} C(x,x,refl_x) \equiv \Pi_{x:A} D(x) \to D(x)$, namely $c: \equiv \lambda x. id_{D(x)}$. So, by path induction there is a function $f: \Pi_{x,y:A} \Pi_{p:x =_A y} C(x,y,p) \equiv \Pi_{x,y:A} \Pi_{p:x =_A y} D(x) \to D(y)$ such that $f(x,x,refl_x) :\equiv c(x) \equiv id_{D(x)}$. This is exactly the statement of indiscernability of identiticals given earlier in the section.

Note: Stringing the judgemental equalities together may be a little sloppy. I was just trying to be explicit on when I was using path induction and how the result is judgementally equal to the statement of indiscernability of identicals.